# Reading from text file using StreamReader

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a text file and I'm using a `StreamReader` for read the entire file to a String array (`String[]`). So I'm using the `StreamReader.ReadToEnd().Split()` method for this. But the text file can contain for example a full name (so words which I want to use as one String) so I wrote this file using '|' as separator but when I use `StreamReader.ReadToEnd().Split('|')` the String array contains elements like this "\r\nSomeString". I think it occurs when I'm using `StreamWriter.WriteLine()`.

Is there a way I can handle this problem?

Comment: If you want to parse a text-file use a parser. In the .NET framework there is for example the [`TextFieldParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/parsing-text-files-with-the-textfieldparser-object). (simply add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;`)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try System.IO.File

example:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt");

        // Display the file contents to the console. Variable text is a string.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteText.txt = {0}", text);

        // Example #2
        // Read each line of the file into a string array. Each element
        // of the array is one line of the file.
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");

        // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
        }
        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt"))
        {
            var myArray = line.Split('\t');
        }
```